# how to take multiple columns and stack them into 1 column, and make the old column names a column

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns

I want to take this table
[a table with monsters and columns with skill bonus's most of them null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1si1.png)

|Montername|survival|stealth|...(there is like 20 columns)

|abc.......|1.......|4......|

and I want to quickly stack them so I only have 3 columns,

|Montername|skillbonus|skill|

|abc.......|1.........|Survival|

|abc.......|4.........|stealth|

I know I can manually pull each column as ["monstername",{skill}] and then stack them with concatenate, and then remove the NaN's. Hoping for a quicker solution.

Comment: df = df[['|Monternam', 'skillbonus', 'skill']]

Comment: If the data is in txt format in a file, then two for loops. First for loop to split by \n, then split by '|'. When it strips the second one, use index to concat it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pandas.DataFrame.stack`, which will give you a series with a multi-index, where the first level is your original columns and the second level is your column names.

```
stacked = df.stack()
```

If you want to make this into a dataframe with column labels, you'll need to feed it to `pd.DataFrame()`, reset the index, and rename the columns:

```
stacked = pd.DataFrame(stacked)
stacked = stacked.reset_index()
stacked = stacked.rename(columns = {'level_0': 'Monstername', 'level_1': 'skillbonus', 0: 'skill'})
```

Comment: I guess this solution is assuming you already have it as a pandas dataframe that looks like the screenshot you posted, let me know if you need any help getting it in to that format from a text file or something.

Comment: note for my needs I had to make sure "monstername"  was set as the index.

Comment: ok, my first line sets monstername and skillbonus as index columns. My suggestion would be just to add `stacked = stacked.set_index('Monstername')` as the end because it doesn't mess with column renaming.